# java not peaking to maximum transfer speed, by udp transmission

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp

I have tested speed between two computers using iperf and got around 255 Mbit/sec on 1 Gbps network.

My question is, when I send UDP packets using java at maximum speed java process can, between above tested two computers, network monitor hardly shows above 40 Mbit/sec transmission.

What is restricting java to send UDP packets at rate of around 250 Mbps on 1 Gbps connection?

I have Windows 7 in both computers. Oracle's JDK 1.7.

Comment: 1) Is it 40 Mbit/sec (paragraph 2) or 250 Mbit/sec (paragraph 3) that Java is currently performing at.  2) What is the CPU utilisation like when the test is running - it might not be network-bound.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse, I apologize for late reply

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse, when I use java program to send UDP packets, it is not crossing above speed of 40 Mbps, but when I check speed through iperf, its showing 250 Mbps speed

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse, Java was taking around 25-30% CPU, no other CPU bound processes were running that time, and no other network transmission was there.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse, by the way, using Java program, when I send packets at sender's maximum rate, without reading from disk; and receiver receives at receiver's maximum speed, without writing to disk, i got around 700 Mbps speed over 1 Gbps network. I troubleshooting my application, as it is having many threads, and that might be causing performance issue.